# How to impersonate the database authentication from Firebase Cloud Function with admin privileges?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a set of Firebase Functions that works as an API for an application.

These Firebase Functions connect to the database with admin privileges as this:

```
const serviceAccount = require(`./config/xxx-firebase-adminsdk.json`);
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: DATABASE_URL,
});
```

I was able to create a custom token and I'm receiving/decoding it in the server but I cannot make use of the security rules because the Firebase function is authenticated with admin privileges.

Is there a way of impersonating the credentials or maybe pass a different user when accessing the database?

Answer (score 6):

You can initialize the admin SDK with user-level privileges as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges):

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
    uid: "the-user-id"
  }
}, "some-other-name");
```

"some-other-name" is required if you've already initialized the default instance.  See [initializeApp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin#.initializeApp) for more details.

You obviously have to know the UID of the authenticated user in order to make this work.  Also, it should be clear that you have to init the SDK every time you want to do something with a different user, which means you're going to have to init on every function call where the UID could be different.

Comment: I tried that but it says that "initializeApp" can be called only once. The pattern I'm trying to follow is not that weird, I'm wondering why is not described in the docs, they only say that the uid can be overriden in case you want to lower the access level of the service.

Comment: OK, so you must already be initializing the default FirebaseApp object somewhere else.  You'll have to initialize a non-default instance, giving it a name passed in the second parameter.  I updated the answer to match.

Comment: For anyone: be aware that as of Jun 2022, `databaseAuthVariableOverride` does not work with Firebase Emulators.